# MYSQL dump size variation

Tags: mysql, aws-dms

I have used AWS DMS for migrating 350 Gb of data.

After the migration, I can see that the size of databases in the source and target are not matching, that is there is variation in the size of DBs.

I have checked by taking mysqldump and found that there are variations in the DB size.

Did anybody faced the difference in DB size after the mysql dump?

Comment: please correct the english/grammer.

Comment: can u check now

Comment: It's normal.  table in the source and target have different size of unused space.  Source can have space for deleted rows.  Of course, deleted rows are not included in the dump.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Blais for your reply